# How to select the parameters of the Sliding Mode Control of a Robotic Arm?

Tags: control, robotic-arm, industrial-robot

I working on sliding mode control (SMC) of a 4 DoF manipulator, I don't know
how to select the discontinuity gain matrix, $ K$ , the surface constant (the diagonal gain matrix $\Lambda$  components).